# Apache re-write aaa/bbb/ccc almost working but not quite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to browse to http://ncvp.co.uk/apache/aaa/bbb/ccc and pass aaa/bbb/ccc to a PHP script while maintaining the nice permalink in the browser address bar.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) apache/not_index.php?slug=$1
```

and here's not_index.php:

```
<b>not_index.php</b> for testing Apache rewrite.<br>
This directory contains <em>.htaccess</em>, <em>not_index.php</em> and the empty directory <em>empty_dir</em>.
<?php
echo "<p>\$_GET:</p>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Everything works except if I browse to `http://ncvp.co.uk/apache/empty_dir` I get the correct slug, apart from an extra `/`, but `http://ncvp.co.uk/apache/empty_dir/?slug=empty_dir` is re-written to the address bar.

*18 Feb 15*

Fixed at last! The solution was adding `DirectoryIndex apache/not_index.php`, so .htaccess now reads:

```
DirectoryIndex apache/not_index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) apache/not_index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: That sounds suspect. Add a `[L]` flag (which you should have anyway) but also clear your browser's cache or test it in a different browser. Some (notoriously Firefox) may suddenly substitute a URL from the history when you try to type in a rewritten URL to test, and work really hard to supply that history URL instead of the similar one you intend. You aren't doing a redirect `[R]` so there's no reason the address bar should change unless the browser is just misbehaving.

Comment: Wait, does `empty_dir` actually exist as a directory?  Typically you would also want `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` in addition to the condition you already have.

Comment: I get exactly the same results in Firefox and Chrome, and it makes no difference if I close the browsers. `empty_dir` does actually exist as a directory, but a slug could have the same name as a directory. I've just tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` but I get '403 Forbidden' if I try to browse to ncvp.co.uk/apache or to ncvp.co.uk/empty_dir

Answer (score 0):

That is due to `mod_dir` adding a trailing slash after a directory. Have your rules like this:

```
# turn auto trailing slash off
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ apache/not_index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I've tried your suggested rules but I get exactly the same address bar `http://ncvp.co.uk/apache/empty_dir/?slug=empty_dir` when I browse to `http://ncvp.co.uk/apache/empty_dir`

Comment: That is due to your browser cache. Test in a new browser or clear browser cache.

Comment: As I explained in the comment above I get the same behaviour in Firefox and Chrome, and if I close and re-open the browsers.

Comment: open and close won't help unless you clear browser cache. This is properly tested and verified code on my end.

Comment: Same behaviour observed with Android browser

Comment: I have also tested several times with several browser and it worked all the time. There is no way it can add a trailing slash with `DirectorySlash Off`